# How Can I List All Unicode Characters Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to programmatically generate and display all 1,111,998 unicode characters using Javascript.

For example, in Haskell, `putStrLn ['a'..]` will display most of them.
Is there a way to do this in Javascript without having to resort to lookup tables?

Comment: use a loop and String.fromCharCode(i)

Comment: @dandavis the OP asks for characters (without lookup tables), not code-points.

Comment: i was under the impression that the method called "fromCharCode" produced a character...

Comment: @dandavid: consider for example range U+D800 to U+DFFF... are they characters or codepoints.. (hint.. it's the last). javascript internally is ucs2..

Comment: good point; how euro-centric of me. LUT it is then. (and a font that has Klingon...)